# Accessibility and tab button

Tags: accessibility

I have a question regarding the accessibility rules and the use of the keyboard.
In a site that I created it is possible to navigate almost the entire site using the TAB key. The only exception is a menu, where you have to use the arrows once you're inside. I share the image of the site.
[image]
On this site I can get to the 'Home tab' using the TAB button, at this point to switch to the other tabs (profile, images, upload) I have to use the keyboard arrows because if I press TAB I end up on Button1 below. At this point I wonder, is the site to be considered accessible or not? Do I need to make all tabs reachable via the TAB key?

Comment: Can you post a link to an example page or some code instead of just a screenshot please? It's hard to answer. Depending on the kind of menu, it may be indeed very good to have items reachable with arrow keys rather than tab.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering for keyboard-only users**

What you've described is fine. If you can tab to the menu, and then use the arrow keys to navigate within tabs, that's keyboard access. Will users know to interact using arrow keys? It's very common to interact with tabs, menus, and lists using the arrow keys, so I believe a user would consider that intuitive. Also, the left/right keyboard navigation is *recommended* by the [W3C's WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices Guide for the Tabs Pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/tabs/).

So, it's both possible *and intuitive* for keyboard-only users to interact with the whole page (per your description).

**Answering for screen reader users**
Using the arrow keys are fine and expected, assuming that the tabs also have the proper roles (`role=tab`, `aria-selected`)